# Is this factorization problem in EXP?

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-complexity, computational-number-theory, integer-sequences, factorization

Factorization is not known to have a polynomial time algorithm. Traditionally the input length is number of bits in representation of the integer to be factored.

However now consider integers of form $2^k\pm1$ where input is now $k$ whose representation length in number of bits is now logarithm of number of bits to represent $2^k\pm1$.

For these numbers since factors are witnesses, the decision problem related to computing the factors is in $NEXP$ (in fact in $UEXP$). Is decision problem of factorization of these numbers in $EXP$? For that matter is computing factors in $PSPACE$ (essentially polynomial time but computation in parallel over exponential number of machines)?